# Can't make Minecraft executeable

Tags: minecraft

I'm right-clicking the `minecraft.jar` file and going under the <kbd>Properties</kbd> tab and there is no checkbox that allows the file to be executable.

Neither the <kbd>Open With</kbd> nor <kbd>command options</kbd> are working either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

`JAR` files are not executable in the same way as shell scripts and programs are. Rather, you need `java` to run them.

## Check to see if you have Java Installed

Run the following:

```
java -version
```

If you get something like this, you have it installed and you can skip the `Installation` step. If not, continue with the `Installation` Step.
[image: "java -version" terminal output]

## Installation (If you don't have Java Installed)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre
```

## The Fun Part :)

Now, after all that hard work, now you can run it! :)

Run:

```
java -jar filename
```

where `filename` is the name of the `JAR` file.

If you have any questions / comments, please comment on this answer. :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `minecraft-installer`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:minecraft-installer-peeps/minecraft-installer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install minecraft-installer
```

Once installed, run Minecraft from the menu / Dash, login with your Minecraft account and the installation should start automatically.

<sub>[Source](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/easily-install-minecraft-in-ubuntu-via.html)</sub>